# Move 2 matches to solve this equation, 28 + 3 = 26

Tags: matches

Please help me solve this equation,  28 + 3 = 26, I tried plus and minus equations, but I can't seem to solve this puzzle

Answer (score 15):

The answer here is:

> 28 + 3 = 26
>  20 + 9 = 26   — Move the middle stick off the 8 to the fill in the top of the 3 for 9
>  20 + 6 = 26   — Move the top-right of the 9 to the bottom left to make a 6

Answer (score 6):

28 + 3

turns into

> 26 + 9

which becomes

> 26 + 0

Answer (score 3):

One more solution for this equation:

28 + 3 = 26

is

> 98 - 3 = 26 < match from plus to make 9 from 2

then

> 98 - 3 = 95 < match from six to make 9 from 2

Comment: Does moving the match described in the first step not make an 8?

Comment: Perhaps the + is made by overlapping two matches.

Comment: How does 2 plus a match become a 9?

Answer (score 0):

(Note: my answer is inequalities, not an equation.)

As there are no restrictions listed:

> 20 - 3 ≠ 28 (really you can just move any two matches to get the `does not equal sign`. I chose moving the middle part of the `8` to make the `does not equal sign` and the vertical part of the `plus sign` to make the `6` and `8`).

Or:

> Depending on how you define "move" you could just tilt the equals sign so you'd get
>  28 + 3 > 26

But those probably aren't what you are looking for

Comment: The question asks for an equation, these are inequalities

Comment: @Jay.  True.  However, most people don't know the difference and they are often synonymous (I didn't think about it when I posted this)

Answer (score 0):

Well

> If you are allowed to "double up" on matches for any edge, you can do 25 + 3 = 28 or 28 - 2 = 26. Both generate an extra match that you can double up an edge with.